# Send String to Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, notifications, swift3

I'm trying create a simple UI here on my iOS app to test a thing or two out but I'm having some issues here. My app is set up with a UITextField and UIButton. I'm trying to replace a string on my .js file which is saved on my virtual server. In my .js file I have below:

```
// Prepare a new notification
var notification = new apn.Notification();

// Display the following message (the actual notification text, supports emoji)
notification.alert = 'Hi James';
```

I basically would like to replace "Hi James" with whatever I typed in the UITextField in my Swift 3 project but not too sure where to start. This would be my first time sending data to .js file so anything would help. I'm thinking so far that it'd be something along the lines to below. Node.js would be similar to Javascript since it's cross platform.

```
func sendSomething(stringToSend : String) {
    appController?.evaluateInJavaScriptContext({ (context) -> Void in 

    //Get a reference to the "myJSFunction" method that you've implemented in JavaScript 
    let myJSFunction = evaluation.objectForKeyedSubscript("myJSFunction") 

    //Call your JavaScript method with an array of arguments 
    myJSFunction.callWithArguments([stringToSend]) }, completion: { (evaluated) -> Void in 
    print("we have completed: \(evaluated)") 
    }) 
}
```

Found that on a relevant StackOverflow post so I feel like I'm getting close. Any assistant would be appreciated in advanced. Have a good one!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the Node **HTTP** or ExpressJS server reading the **POST** fields and posting a document from your iOS app with the desired field

See

https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/anatomy-of-an-http-transaction/

Comment: I'm thinking the "Echo Server Example" would work perfect for my situation. So if I send a POST of basically a String to my .js file on my server, how can I also run the script after I edit the "notification.alert = '[SENT FROM POST]'; "? Similar to just running the .js file in Terminal by typing "node hello.js" I hope this makes sense lol